# Friction when a body just begins to move

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

I was solving a mechanics problem from a book called Problems in Physics for IIT-JEE , the solution for a question is something I'm not convinced with. It goes like-

> In the arrangement shown in the figure the coefficient of friction between the blocks C and
> D is $\mu_1$ = 0.7 and that between block D and the
> horizontal table is $\mu_2$ = 0.2. The system is released
> from rest. (Take $g = 10\ ms^{–2}$) Pulleys and threads
> are massless.[image]

Part 2 of the problem was

> Block B is replaced with a new block. What
> shall be the minimum mass of this new block
> so that block C and D accelerate in opposite
> direction?

The answer they've given is $2.1\ kg$.

I think the answer should be $3\ kg$. Equations for the 2nd block of new mass $m$ will be.
$$mg-T = ma$$
As the string is connected to D and both friction From upper block and table act on it so

$$T - F_1 - F_2 = 1.5a$$

Therfore, $F_1 = 9N$ and $F_2 = 21 N$ solving the eqns and letting acceleration of mass tend to zero as we need it to just be enough to move in opp direction answer obtained is 3kg. Their explanation says that as block would just start moving friction changes from static to kinetic and $F_2 = 0N$ and we obtain $m=2.1\ kg$.

Comment: You've got to determine the mass of block B that results in the maximum possible static friction force between C and D to be exceeded.

Comment: The question was worded in a way that can mislead the reader into believing this is a dynamics problem when it actually is a very simple statics problem

Answer (score 2):

The sum of the forces in the x direction is equal to zero for the static case.

$$m_Ag - \mu_2(m_C+m_D)g -\mu_1m_Cg  + \mu_1m_Cg -m_Bg = 0$$

Canceling out g gives:

$$m_B = m_A - \mu_2(m_C + m_D)$$

For the static case $m_B = 2.1 kg$ and for the block to accelerate $m_B > 2.1 kg$